# How do I get image to display above each <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the image to display above each list item, which needs to be displayed inline. I've tried increasing the padding for the image on .ccs but it doesn't look right. Any advice would be great.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="frontpageproducts">
<ul>
    <li><a href="<%= url_prefix %>dac?no-upsell=1"><img src="img/front-page/application.png">Order Domains</a></li>        
    <li><a href="<%= url_prefix %>package-chooser?no-upsell=1"><img src="img/front-page/application.png">Order Web Hosting</a></li>      
    <li><a href="<%= url_prefix %>dedicated-servers?no-upsell=1"><img src="img/front-page/application.png">Order Servers</a></li>       
    <li><a href="<%= url_prefix %>vps?no-upsell=1"><img src="img/front-page/application.png">Order VPS</a></li>      
    <li><a href="<%= url_prefix %>add-ons?no-upsell=1"><img src="img/front-page/application.png">Order Add-ons</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#frontpageproducts li{
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
display: inline;
font-size: 15px;
list-style: none;   

}

#frontpageproducts img{
display:inline-block;
padding-left: 30px; 
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/11/

Comment: @RohitAzad that fiddle doesn't work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `br` tags after the images and make the `li`'s inline blocks

http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/4/

Images centered

http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/9/

**EDIT**

As many people are stating (i did note it in the comments) giving the image `display:block` does bump it on its own line. this means you do not need the `br` tags.

Comment: +1 Another solution would be using `<br>` + `float`ing the list items.

Comment: @HashemQolami True... floated `li`'s http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/10/ **note** if you use this method make sure you `clear:both` before the next element or you could have overlapping

Comment: @Adween thank you again for your input, first method works fine

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods to achieve this. What I did here http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/14/  is giving `display:block` for img and minor edits in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you. I hate <br> thats why.. :D

Comment: @noob i love em! nah was the first thing that popped in my head. i'll add it

Comment: @noob This is a really nice way to do it. Thank you for showing me this never thought there were so many ways!

Answer (score 1):

you should `display:inline-block` your `li` and then , you can set `img` as `block` : http://jsfiddle.net/kcNa9/15/

```
#frontpageproducts li{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none;   

    }
#frontpageproducts img{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

Comment: ahhh the secret 4th option! : )

Comment: should be the first and simpliest to set :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you for your input. This is another really nice way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent div width to `100%` and set the `width` of `ul` to `95%`. Then set the `width` of `li` to `45%`, so that only two would come in a row.

Refer to the fiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekverma3189/N6G83/